# Embedded function returns None

Tags: python, function

My function returns `None`. I have checked to make sure all the operations are correct, and that I have a return statement for each function.

```py
def parameter_function(principal, annual_interest_rate, duration):
    n = float(duration * 12)
    if annual_interest_rate == 0:
        r = float(principal / n)
    else:
        r = float(annual_interest_rate / 1200)
    p = principal
    return (p, r, n)

    def monthly_payment_function(p, r, n):
        monthly_payment = p * ((r * ((1 + r) ** n)) / (((1 + r) ** n) - 1))

    result = monthly_payment_function(p, r, n)
    return result
```

Comment: Please don't edit your questions in ways that invalidate existing answers. In particular, don't apply corrections from answers to the code posted in your question.

Comment: It's perfectly permissible to _add_ follow-on information to your question, but if that changes the original question too much, you're best bet would be to post a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`monthly_payment_function` does not return anything. Replace `monthly_payment=` with `return` (that's 'return' followed by a space).

Also you have an unconditional `return` before `def monthly_payment_function`, meaning it never gets called (strictly speaking, it never even gets defined).

Also you are pretty randomly mixing units, and your variable names could use some help:

```
from __future__ import division    # Python 2.x: int/int gives float

MONTHS_PER_YEAR = 12

def monthly_payment(principal, pct_per_year, years):
    months = years * MONTHS_PER_YEAR
    if pct_per_year == 0:
        return principal / months
    else:
        rate_per_year   = pct_per_year / 100.
        rate_per_month  = rate_per_year / MONTHS_PER_YEAR
        rate_compounded = (1. + rate_per_month) ** months - 1.
        return principal * rate_per_month * (1. + rate_compounded) / rate_compounded
```

Comment: It should always return  (p, r, n), so return type of monthly_payment_function doesn't matter here

Comment: Thank you I made those changes but the code continues not to work. I edited the code above.