# Loan payment calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x, finance

I am learning Python and am stuck. I am trying to find the loan payment amount. I currently have:

```
def myMonthlyPayment(Principal, annual_r, n):
    years = n
    r = ( annual_r / 100 ) / 12
    MonthlyPayment = (Principal * (r * ( 1 + r ) ** years / (( 1 + r ) ** (years - 1))))
    return MonthlyPayment

n=(input('Please enter number of years of loan'))
annual_r=(input('Please enter the interest rate'))
Principal=(input('Please enter the amount of loan'))
```

However, when I run, I am off by small amount. If anyone can point to my error, it would be great. I am using Python 3.4.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35375449/embedded-function-returns-none/35375462#35375462

Answer (score 3):

Payment calculation-wise, you don't appear to have translated the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_calculator#Monthly_payment_formula) correctly. Besides that, since the built-in `input()` function returns strings, you'll need to convert whatever it returns to the proper type before passing the values on to the function which expects them to numeric values.

```
def myMonthlyPayment(Principal, annual_r, years):
    n = years * 12  # number of monthly payments
    r = (annual_r / 100) / 12  # decimal monthly interest rate from APR
    MonthlyPayment = (r * Principal * ((1+r) ** n)) / (((1+r) ** n) - 1)
    return MonthlyPayment

years = int(input('Please enter number of years of loan: '))
annual_r = float(input('Please enter the annual interest rate: '))
Principal = int(input('Please enter the amount of loan: '))

print('Monthly payment: {}'.format(myMonthlyPayment(Principal, annual_r, years)))
```

Comment: P.S. The syntax highlighting of the code looks odd because it doesn't follow [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

I think in the last bit of your calculation,

```
/ (( 1 + r ) ** (years - 1))
```

you have your bracketing wrong; it should be

```
/ ((( 1 + r ) ** years) - 1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this makes the calculation further off. Any other idea? It is of by about a value of 2. I almost feel that there is some type of rounding error.

Comment: @S-Mason: can you give a sample: p, r, n and expected output?

Comment: 30 years, 20% interest, 10,000 Principal   yields:            
169.444444444 
should be
167.101868625

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct formula is this,

```
MonthlyPayment = (Principal * r) / (1 - (1 + r) ** (12 * years))
```

I cleaned up your variables some,

```
def get_monthly_payment(principal, annual_rate, years):
    monthly_rate = annual_rate / 100 / 12
    monthly_payment = principal * (monthly_rate + monthly_rate / ((1 + monthly_rate) ** (12 * years) - 1))
    return monthly_payment

years = float((input('Please enter number of years of loan')))
annual_rate = float((input('Please enter the interest rate')))
principal = float((input('Please enter the amount of loan')))
print ("Monthly Payment: " + str(get_monthly_payment(principal, annual_rate, years)))
```

It would also be prudent to add a try-except block around the inputs.

Comment: If `r > 0` then `(1 + r) ** (12 * years) > 1` so `(1 - (1 + r) ** (12 * years))` gives a negative result. *Negative payments* means your formula is wrong.

Comment: Right you are, Hugh. Thanks for catching that. I copied that formula from WikiHow, and I'm positive I coded it exactly as they had it, but it's wrong. I corrected my response above based on what I hope is the right formula. I still don't like using r to designate monthly interest rate or n for number of months because only the person who wrote it will understand it, and even he won't remember his own variable definitions 3 months later.